# Invalid computation of maxima

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am finding the following minimum

```
FindMinimum[{
Abs[
ArgMax[f[q, n, b, b0, b1, t, s], b] - b1
]
}, {b1, -0.5}]
```

given `q=3/5, b0=1, t=3/2, s=1` and obtain the following graph for `n = {5,...,25}`:

[image]

My question is about the values at 13, 16, and 24. Why am I having these irregular and apparently wrong values and is there a way to get rid of this problem? Is this a problem of precision? Also, is it possible to make this computation faster?

**Update**
Upon requests in comments, I give the definitions here. 
Function f is

```
f[q_, n_, b_, b0_, b1_, t_, s_] := Sum[(Binomial[n - 1, k]*t^(n - 1 - k)/(1 + t)^(n - 1)*g[q, n, b, k*b0 + (n - 1 - k)*b1, s]), {k, 0, n - 1}]
```

where function g is

```
g[q_, n_, b_, B_, s_] = (q*(Probability[x + b + B + 1/2 s^2 Log[q/(1 - q)] > 0, 
 x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[n, s*n^(1/2)]]) + (1 -
  q)*(Probability[x + b + B + 1/2 s^2 Log[q/(1 - q)] < 0, 
 x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[-n, s*n^(1/2)]]))
```

Here is the plotting procedure, to make it easy for your replication. I set the function:

```
bb[q_, n_, b0_, t_, s_]:=b1/.Last[FindMinimum[{Abs[ArgMax[f[q,n,b,b0,b1,t,s],b]-b1]},{b1,-0.5}]]
```

and then plot with

```
DiscretePlot[bb[3/5,m,1,3/2,1],{m,5,25}]
```

In place of `FindMinimum` I used `FindRoot` as in

```
FindRoot[ArgMax[f[q,n,b,b0,b1,t,s],b]-b1==0,{b1,-0.5}]
```

and also, in another try, I got replaced `Abs` with conditions as in

```
FindMinimum[{ArgMax[f[q,n,b,b0,b1,t,s],b]-b1,ArgMax[f[q,n,b,b0,b1,t,s],b]-b1>0},{b1,-0.5}]
```

both of which did not help.

Finally, to show another proof that the problem with this deterministic computation is totally random, I present here one more plot, where I replace `1` with `1.0001` for parameter `s`.

Here is when `s=1.0001`

[image]

Comment: Could you explain "an expected normal probability of binomial values" further?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius It is actually `Sum[(Binomial[n - 1, k]*t^(n - 1 - k)/(1 + t)^(n - 1)*g[q, n, b, k*b0 + (n - 1 - k)*b1, s]), {k, 0, n - 1}]` where the function g is really an error function (normal probability).

Comment: *edit the question* to include the definition of `f` and `g`

Comment: Please don't change the tags ... again

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Ok.

Comment: @george2079 I did accordingly.

Comment: Please add the left hand side of your functions (like `f[x_, y_]:= ....`)

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I did accordingly.

Comment: make `g` a plain `=`, not `SetDelayed (:=) `. That will speed it up considerably.  Also I think `NArgMax` will be faster.  With those changes I dont see your anomolies ( `-.603 @ 16` )

Comment: @george2079 I replaced `ArgMax` with `NArgMax` but that did not help. Honestly, I don't get what you mean by putting `=` in place of `:=`. Could you explain a bit how would that work?

Comment: @george2079 OK, I got it now but I still have the same problem. Not at 16 but in other values. It seems like this question is out of sight now. What should I do to regain attention? Should I delete this and write anew?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius It seems like this question is out of sight now, and not resolved. What should I do to regain attention? Should I delete this and write anew?

Comment: @juror You're using `FindMinimum[ ]` which detects local extrema. I believe you're converging to non-optimal points

Comment: When you edit the question it moves up on the active list.  Suggest you make the suggested change (`=`) and update the graphic.

Comment: @george2079 Agree. The result doesn't show outliers at all. Care to post an answer?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I tried other approaches than `FindMinimum`, like `FindRoot`. That might do the same but what should I do in case of converging to non-optimal points?

Comment: @juror Use `NMinimize[ ]`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Thanks, but `NMinimize` doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to improve on this situation. SOme involve making these functions into "black boxes" that only work for explicit numeric input. That removes all symbolic preprocessing, along with warning messages that get produced there. Another is to force use of a the interior point method. This can be done by adding a constraint e.g. `b1<=0`. Or use Newton's method; that also seems to give a viable result.

For either of the above there is an important subtlety. They like differentiable functions. We have an `Abs` defining the objective function. Since it is a discrepancy we are measuring, we can just as well use the square of the value. In here lurks another subtlety: we want the squaring to be explicitly seen in `FindMinimum` and not part of the black-box function.

Also it seems like a good idea to use the numeric arg-max since it will be faster. The reson is that "exact" `ArgMax` will punt to `NMinimize` when given approximate input, whereas `NArgMax` will invoke the typically faster `FindMaximum`.

So here is the code.

```
q = 3/5;
b0 = 1;
t = 3/2;
s = 1.0001;

f[q_, n_?NumberQ, b_, b0_, b1_, t_, s_] := 
 Sum[(Binomial[n - 1, k]*t^(n - 1 - k)/(1 + t)^(n - 1)*
    g1[q, n, b, k*b0 + (n - 1 - k)*b1, s]), {k, 0, n - 1}]

g[q_, n_, b_, B_, 
   s_] = (q*(Probability[x + b + B + 1/2 s^2 Log[q/(1 - q)] > 0, 
       x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[n, s*n^(1/2)]]) + (1 - 
       q)*(Probability[x + b + B + 1/2 s^2 Log[q/(1 - q)] < 0, 
       x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[-n, s*n^(1/2)]]));

g1[q_, n_?NumberQ, b_, B_, s_] := g[q, n, b, B, s]

argmaxfN[q_, n_?NumberQ, b_, b0_, b1_?NumberQ, t_, 
  s_] := (NArgMax[f[q, n, b, b0, b1, t, s], b] - b1)
```

So here goes.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Table[
    FindMinimum[argmaxfN[q, n, b, b0, b1, t, s]^2, {b1, -0.5}, 
     Method -> "Newton"], {n, 5, 25}];]

<a few warnings snipped>

(* Out[108]= {53.415487, Null} *)

ListPlot[b1 /. res[[All, 2]]]
```

[image]

As noted earlier, one can force usage of interior point code by adding a constraint.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Table[
    FindMinimum[{argmaxfN[q, n, b, b0, b1, t, s]^2, 
      b1 <= 0}, {b1, -0.5}], {n, 5, 25}];]

During evaluation of In[110]:= NArgMax::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations. >>

During evaluation of In[110]:= NArgMax::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations. >>

During evaluation of In[110]:= NArgMax::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations. >>

During evaluation of In[110]:= General::stop: Further output of NArgMax::cvmit will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

(* Out[110]= {54.747887, Null} *)
```

The plot is pretty much the same as before, so I omit it.